# Modify XML file based on partial name

Tags: bash, xml

I've been using [Xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) to modify some `.xml` files but I am lost trying to figure out how to modify a tag based on a partial name.  What is the best way to comment out an entire line that begins with `<` and ends with `>` when the line has a name of `spiral` in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use **sed** for that task:

```
sed -r -e 's/^<(.*spiral.*)>$/<!--\1-->/'
```

Demo:

```
$ cat test.xml 
<some line here>
<other spiral line here>
$ sed -i -r -e 's/^<(.*spiral.*)>$/<!--\1-->/' test.xml 
$ cat test.xml 
<some line here>
<!--other spiral line here-->
```